# Order full text search by exact match THEN prefixed matches

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How can I ensure my full text search results are ordered by exact matches and THEN prefixed matches?

```
SELECT ticker, name, ts_rank(document, to_tsquery('english', 'MAT:*')) AS rank
FROM (
  SELECT *, setweight(to_tsvector('english', ticker), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('english', name), 'B') AS document
  FROM ( VALUES
     ('MATI-R' , 'MATICHON PCL.NVDR')
    ,('MATCH-R', 'MATCHING MAXIMIZE SLN. NVDR')
    ,('MATV'   , 'MATAV-CABLE SYS.MEDIA SPN.ADR 1:2 DEAD - DELIST.03/07/06')
    ,('MAT'    , 'MATISSE HOLDINGS DEAD - 03/10/06')
    ,('MAT'    , 'MATTEL')
  ) data (ticker,name)
) ss ORDER BY rank DESC
```

I tried a few of the suggestions on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-textsearch.html like `to_tsquery('english', 'MAT:A & MAT:*B')` but none seem to give me the ordering I'm looking for. The current output is

```
 ticker  |                           name                           |   rank   
---------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------
 MATI-R  | MATICHON PCL.NVDR                                        |  1.45903
 MATCH-R | MATCHING MAXIMIZE SLN. NVDR                              |  1.27665
 MATV    | MATAV-CABLE SYS.MEDIA SPN.ADR 1:2 DEAD - DELIST.03/07/06 |  1.09427
 MAT     | MATISSE HOLDINGS DEAD - 03/10/06                         | 0.851098
 MAT     | MATTEL                                                   | 0.851098
```

when I want something more like

```
 ticker  |                           name                           |   rank
---------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------
 MAT     | MATTEL                                                   | ??
 MAT     | MATISSE HOLDINGS DEAD - 03/10/06                         | ??
 MATCH-R | MATCHING MAXIMIZE SLN. NVDR                              | ??
 MATI-R  | MATICHON PCL.NVDR                                        | ??
 MATV    | MATAV-CABLE SYS.MEDIA SPN.ADR 1:2 DEAD - DELIST.03/07/06 | ??
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LIKE` or `ILIKE`:

```
SELECT ticker, name, ts_rank(document, to_tsquery('english', 'MAT:*')) AS rank
FROM (
  SELECT *, setweight(to_tsvector('english', ticker), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('english', name), 'B') AS document
  FROM ( VALUES
     ('MATI-R' , 'MATICHON PCL.NVDR')
    ,('MATCH-R', 'MATCHING MAXIMIZE SLN. NVDR')
    ,('MATV'   , 'MATAV-CABLE SYS.MEDIA SPN.ADR 1:2 DEAD - DELIST.03/07/06')
    ,('MAT'    , 'MATISSE HOLDINGS DEAD - 03/10/06')
    ,('MAT'    , 'MATTEL')
  ) data (ticker,name)
) ss ORDER BY name LIKE concat('%', ticker, '%') desc, rank DESC

 ticker  |                           name                           |   rank   
---------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------
 MAT     | MATISSE HOLDINGS DEAD - 03/10/06                         | 0.851098
 MAT     | MATTEL                                                   | 0.851098
 MATI-R  | MATICHON PCL.NVDR                                        |  1.45903
 MATCH-R | MATCHING MAXIMIZE SLN. NVDR                              |  1.27665
 MATV    | MATAV-CABLE SYS.MEDIA SPN.ADR 1:2 DEAD - DELIST.03/07/06 |  1.09427
(5 rows)
```

Comment: This is interesting. Seems like it works if we sort on `ticker` instead of `name` but it also seems a little hacky as it skips the ranking capability of postgresql's full text search. It would seem like the using the full text search ranking would be more performant on a larger dataset. Any reason you'd suggest this method over one that uses the full text search machinery?

Comment: First, you cannot find exact matches like this only with full text search. Using `like` is not instead of full text search but rather next to it. Both features work well together. Of course, `like` will be more expensive on large data sets but I cannot see alternatives to achieve what you want.

Comment: Makes sense. We're playing with some of the normalization weights now and seeing pretty good results but I think we're going to end up with some combination of your solution and those.